# Multiprocessing results in PicklingError

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pickle

Executing the example

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def f(name):
    print 'hello', name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

from the python documentation for the package `multiprocessing` results in a `PicklingError: Can't pickle <function f at 0x05A57830>: it's not found as __main__.f`.

How can i solve this ?

*the complete error message is*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\startup.py", line 128, in runfile
    execfile(filename, glbs)
  File "C:\Users\Ruben\Desktop\untitled0.py", line 15, in <module>
    p.start()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\multiprocessing-2.6.2.1-py2.7-win32.egg\multiprocessing\process.py", line 109, in start
    self._popen = Popen(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\multiprocessing-2.6.2.1-py2.7-win32.egg\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 244, in __init__
    dump(process_obj, to_child, HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\multiprocessing-2.6.2.1-py2.7-win32.egg\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 167, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 419, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 681, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 748, in save_global
    (obj, module, name))
PicklingError: Can't pickle <function f at 0x05A57830>: it's not found as __main__.f
```

Comment: It works just fine for me ... (prints "hello bob")

Comment: i tested it on 3 computers and it works only at 1 of 3 (?)

Comment: I'm 2 for 2 (Ubuntu Linux desktop, OS-X Leopard mac-book).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/29) in IPython. You are running the code from the ipython console:

```
File "<ipython console>", line 1, in <module>
```

where `__main__` [references a FakeModule](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/29) and pickle can not find `__main__.f` :

```
PicklingError: Can't pickle <function f at 0x05A57830>: it's not found as __main__.f
```

(`multiprocessing` uses `pickle` to pass functions and arguments to the worker processes.)

So the solution is to run your code as a script, not from `ipython`.